# Getting a plot to show when plot function is imported into mainscript

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot

I made a simple function for a plot - it works, but when i import the function into my mainscript, it does not show before inside my "menu" while the while loop is running. Normally i use `plt.show()` but, we've made the plot with a pd.DataFrame. Any ideas?

```
def plotGrades(newGrades):

    t = newGrades['Final Grade'].value_counts().sort_index().plot("bar",title="Final grades",x="jfh")
    return t
```

Comment: still `plt.show()` would work.

Comment: Drop the `return` statement. When you call the function it will get plotted.

Comment: `DataFrame.plot()` should return an axes object.